# C# winform - Raise a personal event in Timer_tick event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, timer, event-handling

I have create a small class CountDown , that contains a timer.

Class is very simple : receive time target, and start a CountDown with a timer.

When target is reached, my personal event fire:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CountDownWithEvent
{
    public delegate void countDownFinishEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e);
    class CountDown
    {
        private DateTime _target;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;
        System.TimeSpan _timeMissing;


        public event countDownFinishEventHandler CountDownFinish;

        public CountDown(DateTime targetTime)
        {
            this._target = targetTime;
            this._timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            this._timeMissing = new TimeSpan();
        }

        public DateTime TargetTime
        {
            get;
        }

        public TimeSpan timeMissing
        {
            get;
        }

        public void CountDownStart()
        {
            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);
            _timer.Start();
        }

        protected virtual void timer_tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (_timer.Tick != null)
            //{
            //}
            System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
            _timeMissing = _target.Subtract(now);
            if (!(timeMissing.TotalSeconds > 0))
            {
                _timer.Stop();
                if(CountDownFinish != null)
                {
                    EventArgs b = new EventArgs();
                    CountDownFinish(this, b);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CountDownWithEvent
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CountDown CountDown = new CountDown(new DateTime(2016, 05, 27, 14, 48, 00));
            CountDown.CountDownFinish += new countDownFinishEventHandler(onCountDown);
            CountDown.CountDownStart();
        }

        private void onCountDown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("time expired! ");
        }
    }
}
```

I use EventArgs, rather than write a derived class , because I don't need any special information of the event ( to understand, parameter **e**)

now I'm in a situation a bit unusual :

```
protected virtual void timer_tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (_timer.Tick != null)
        //{
        //}
        System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
        _timeMissing = _target.Subtract(now);
        if (!(timeMissing.TotalSeconds > 0))
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            if(CountDownFinish != null)
            {
                EventArgs b = new EventArgs();
                CountDownFinish(this, b);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i call `CountdownFinish(this,e);`  the *e* parameter refer an timer_tick 
It isn t consistent pass EventArgs timer
so I don t know how to behave ???

In fact I have instantiated new `EventArgs b`

```
            EventArgs b = new EventArgs();
            CountDownFinish(this, b);
```

but I don't know if this is the right path

Now i'm another problem :

I want to see in label the time left to goal. And refresh it to any timer_tick.
whereas I want to keep separated the timer logic of the program graphic..
*how I can do it?*

Many thanks in advance for the understanding and the help!
(sorry for bad english, isn't my language :) )

Comment: If you solved your problem don't add another question to the same post, ask new one instead.

Comment: thank for ask.. but  i haven't solved... 
the first is a doubt .. the second is the problem

Comment: **1-** To provides a value to use with events that do not have event data use [`EventArgs.Empty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.empty(v=vs.110).aspx).
 **2-** Create `TimeLeft` property which shows remaining time to finish and decrease it in the timer tick event. Also create `TimeLeftChanged` event which fires when `TimeLeft` changes.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks. 
If i create a property that decrease ... how to refresh label ?! This is the passage that I miss ( I hope to have past my difficulty) .. Whereas `CountDown` and `Form` is a separate class...`Also create TimeLeftChanged event which fires when TimeLeft changes`  with this solution how to pass data to label ? create a member class in `CountDown` type label ?

Comment: In the form, subscribe `TimeLeftChanged` event of your component and in the method which handles the event set the text of label to value of `TimeLeft` property of the component.

Comment: thanks @RezaAghaei . Below , write _solution_ ... 
if you mean other ways or other to improve this solution I'll listen gladly :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei if u have a possibility , read my solution and question that
followed in bottom..

Comment: @rul3z Sure, I checked it. Sorry, I couldn't remember why I missed your comment at Jun 1. Probably I was in middle of answering another question and I saw other notifications but didn't see it. Sorry for late reply :)

Answer (score 1):

@Reza Aghaei

ok, this is my solution ..
What do you think ?!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EventsTry
{
    public delegate void countDownFinishEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e);
    public delegate void TimeLeftChangedEventHandler(Object sender, TimeLeftDateEventArgs e);
    class CountDown
    {
        private DateTime _target;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;
        System.TimeSpan _timeMissing;

        public event countDownFinishEventHandler CountDownFinish;
        public event TimeLeftChangedEventHandler TimeLeftChanged;

        public CountDown(DateTime targetTime)
        {
            this._target = targetTime;
            this._timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            this._timeMissing = new TimeSpan();
        }

        public DateTime TargetTime
        {
            get { return this._target; }
        }

        public TimeSpan timeMissing
        {
            get { return this._timeMissing; }
        }

        public void CountDownStart()
        {
            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);
            _timer.Start();
        }

        protected virtual void timer_tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
            _timeMissing = _target.Subtract(now);


            if (!(timeMissing.TotalSeconds > 0))
            {
                _timer.Stop();


                if (CountDownFinish != null)
                {
                    CountDownFinish(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (TimeLeftChanged != null)
                {
                    TimeLeftChanged(this, new TimeLeftDateEventArgs(timeMissing));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class TimeLeftDateEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private int _hours;
        private int _minutes;
        private int _seconds;

        public TimeLeftDateEventArgs(TimeSpan timespan)
        {
            _hours = timespan.Hours;
            _minutes = timespan.Minutes;
            _seconds = timespan.Seconds;

        }

        public int Hours
        { get { return this._hours; } }

        public int Minutes
        { get { return this._minutes; } }

        public int Seconds
        { get { return this._seconds; } }

    }


}
```

form class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EventsTry
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CountDown CountDown = new CountDown(new DateTime(2016,06,01,11,35,00));
            CountDown.CountDownFinish += new countDownFinishEventHandler(onCountDown);
            CountDown.TimeLeftChanged += new TimeLeftChangedEventHandler(onTimeLeft);
            CountDown.CountDownStart();
        }

        private void onCountDown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("time expired! ");
        }

        private void onTimeLeft(Object sender, TimeLeftDateEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.Hours + ":" + e.Minutes + ":" + e.Seconds;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that delegate `countDownFinishEventHandler` it's equal to `EventHandler`.
I haven t changed out of laziness.

I wanted to use an inner class to `TimeLeftDateEventArgs` but public delegate is extern to class `CountDown` then `TimeLeftDateEventArgs` isn't not accessible to delegate.

> **2-** Create TimeLeft property which shows remaining time to finish and decrease it in the timer tick event.

you meant this solution ? or other way !?

Comment: You are almost there. To create a custom event use [such solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36130796/3110834). But instead of `EventHandler` use `public event EventHandler<TimeLeftDateEventArgs> TimeLeftChanged;`. Also if your `TimeLeftChangedEventArgs` contains enough information, you don't need any other properties for the class. The property which I mentioned in comments was for gaining information which you currently have in your event arg and you can use theme to show on label.

Comment: So to make the answer more useful, edit the answer and add event in the right way.