# User Control with multiple controls handle click

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls

I have a User Control that has 3 labels on it. I would like the click event on the parent form to be raised when the control is clicked at any point on the canvas, even in the labels. Its like a button with 3 labels...right now it will only raise the parent event when the base canvas portion is clicked, but doestn't bubble up when the labels are clicked.
First, in the constructor I assign the event handlers:

```
public partial class RunCodeButton : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler ButtonClick;

    public RunCodeButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LblCode.Click += RunCodeButton_Click;
        LblCount.Click += RunCodeButton_Click;
        LblDescription.Click += RunCodeButton_Click;
    }
}
```

Then I have the click event of the User control added to the class:

```
    private void RunCodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonClick?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
```

then, in the main form (not the user control), i add the click event when I generate the button:

```
 _button.Click += Button_Click;
 private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
        Result = DialogResult.OK;
        RunCode = (Codes_Run)((RunCodeButton)sender).Tag;
        Close();
 }
```

if i set a breakpoint inside the user controls click event, and click on a label. It raises the event, but 'ButtonClick' is always null and it stops there.

Is there a way to make the User controls child controls click event bubble up?

Comment: Is this winforms or WPF?

Comment: Winforms. Sorry

Comment: [Pass click event of child control to the parent control](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36130796/3110834)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
_button.ButtonClick += Button_Click;
```

around the line

```
_button.Click += Button_Click;
```

Although you don't even need `_button.ButtonClick`. Simply do

```
private void RunCodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Click?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```