# How to check if LeftClick is pressed C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to check if a user has left click being held anyone know how I would need to accomplish this?

I already tried messing around with System.Windows.Input but I couldn't figure it out

This is a windows forms app but I need it to work outside of the form I prefer a simpler answer

Comment: What kind of application? Windows Forms, WPF, a console app?

Comment: @Flydog57 It is windows forms I have now edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alot of useful answers on Stack overflow.
Try this >> [c# Detect mouse clicks anywhere (Inside and Outside the Form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068445/c-sharp-detect-mouse-clicks-anywhere-inside-and-outside-the-form)

This should allow you to detect left clicks in or outside your program.
If you want an event for a control in your form, try the .Click event.