# send mouse_event without triggering mouse hook

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, console-application

I'm basically creating an app that as long as you hold down the left click on your mouse, it will execute left clicks in a loop in a specific cooldown, the problem I'm facing is that when you hold down the left click its executing another clicks which makes the program think that you stopped to hold the button, so I'm searching for a way to send mouse_event function
amd make my mouse hook ignore the mouse event function somehow

```
     void mouse_OnMouseActivity(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Utils.dont || !mode)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (mode && !Focused && e.Clicks == 1 && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !down && Threads.Count == 0 && !Utils.dont)
        {
            down = true;
            Console.WriteLine("DOWN");

                    Thread th = new Thread(() => {

                        Workers++;

                        while (!Focused && down && mode)
                        {
                            
                            Console.WriteLine(">> " + Threads.Count+ " | "+Utils.dont);
                            Console.Title = Workers.ToString();



                            Utils.Click();


                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
                        }



                        Workers--;

                    });
                    th.Start();
                   Threads.Add(th);

        }
        else
            {
        
            if (e.Clicks == 2 && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !Utils.dont)
            { 
                down = false;
                Console.WriteLine("UP " + (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left));
                if (Threads.Count != 0)
                {
                    Workers= 0;
                    List<Thread> ToRemove = new List<Thread>();
                    foreach (var thread in Threads)
                    {
                        ToRemove.Add(thread);
                    }

                    foreach(var thread in ToRemove)
                    {
                        Threads.Remove(thread);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068445/c-sharp-detect-mouse-clicks-anywhere-inside-and-outside-the-form

Comment: Do a search for "low level keyboard hook via WH_MOUSE_LL".

Comment: I can't seem to find an working method, everything I find is too old @Idle_Mind

Comment: I assure you, the WH_MOUSE_LL method still works.  Show us what you've tried along with what errors you are getting...

Comment: Actually I just got it working, but now I'm facing another problem, I created an mouse_event to execute a left click, do you know how can I execute a left click without triggering my hook event

Comment: @Idle_Mind if you could help

Comment: You could setup a boolean flag to indicate when the hook should ignore the next click, then send your left click.

Comment: I actually tried that, but it seems there some sort  timing issues cause it doesn't always ignores it

Comment: any idea? @Idle_Mind

Comment: We can't troubleshoot what we can't see.  Post your code and perhaps we can figure it out...